# How to if given a list of integers and a number called x, return recursively the sum of every x'th number in the list

Tags: python, list, recursion, int

So, How to if given a list of integers and a number called x, return recursively the sum of every x'th number in the list.

In this task "indexing" starts from 1, so if `x = 2` and `nums = [2, 3, 4, -9]`, the output should be `-6` (3 + -9).

X can also be negative, in that case indexing starts from the end of the list, see examples below.

If `x = 0`, the sum should be `0` as well.

For example:

```
print(x_sum_recursion([], 3))  # 0
print(x_sum_recursion([2, 5, 6, 0, 15, 5], 3))  # 11
print(x_sum_recursion([0, 5, 6, -5, -9, 3], 1))  # 0
print(x_sum_recursion([43, 90, 115, 500], -2))  # 158
print(x_sum_recursion([1, 2], -9))  # 0
print(x_sum_recursion([2, 3, 6], 5))  # 0
print(x_sum_recursion([6, 5, 3, 2, 9, 8, 6, 5, 4], 3))  # 15
```

I have been trying to do this function for 5 hours straight!!!

Would like do see how someone else would solve this.

This is the best i have come up with.

```
def x_sum_rec_Four(nums: list, x: int) -> int:
    if len(nums) == 0:
        return 0
    elif len(nums) < x:
        return 0
    elif x > 0:
        i = x - 1
        return nums[i] + x_sum_rec_Four(nums[i + x:], x)
    elif x < 0:
        return x_sum_rec_Four(nums[::-1], abs(x))
```

My problem with this recursion is that the finish return should be:

```
if len(nums) < x:
    return nums[0]
```

but that would pass things like `([2, 3, 6], 5))  -->> 2` when it should be 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to do it recursively, you could pop x-1 elements from the list before each call, follow the comments below:

```
def x_sum_recursion(nums, x):
    # if x is negative, call the function with positive x and reversed list
    if x < 0:
        return x_sum_recursion(nums[::-1], abs(x))
    # base case for when x is greater than the length of the list
    if x > len(nums):
        return 0
    # otherwise remove the first x-1 items
    nums = nums[x-1:]
    # sum the first element and remove it from the next call
    return nums[0] + x_sum_recursion(nums[1:], x)

print(x_sum_recursion([], 3))  # 0
print(x_sum_recursion([2, 5, 6, 0, 15, 5], 3))  # 11
print(x_sum_recursion([0, 5, 6, -5, -9, 3], 1))  # 0
print(x_sum_recursion([43, 90, 115, 500], -2))  # 158
print(x_sum_recursion([1, 2], -9))  # 0
print(x_sum_recursion([2, 3, 6], 5))  # 0
print(x_sum_recursion([6, 5, 3, 2, 9, 8, 6, 5, 4], 3))  # 15
```

However, you can do it in a one liner simple and pythonic way:

```
print(sum(nums[x-1::x] if x > 0 else nums[x::x]))
```

**Explanation:**

you slice the list using `nums[start:end:increment]` when you leave the end empty it slices from the starting position till the end of the list and increments by the increment specified

Comment: I would love to do it with a third argument but it MUST be done with 2 arguments! Thats why i have spent 5 hour trying to figure this out. I have a pretty good solution using a third argument but thats no use cause it MUST have only the 2 that are given.

Comment: @master_of_code Could you pop items from the list? or do you have to keep it unchanged for further use?

Comment: I guess, as long as its recursive and returns the right sum.

Comment: @master_of_code edited to be done without adding a third argument

Comment: @Mohd you've left the 3 arg version in your first recursive call

Comment: @Mohd and instead of your loop and pop... You can use `nums[:] = nums[x-1:]` instead

Comment: @JonClements that's indeed a better approach, thanks.